# jQuery float values like php number_format(number, 2 )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need floating number output exactly like number_format function in php.

**Javascript Code**

```
Math.round(totalCredit).toFixed(2)
```

**PHP Code**

```
echo number_format(22212 , 2);
```

above code return me `22,212.00` and this is exactly I want in js.

**Expected output**

> 22.212

Comment: Why would you get `22.212` when you're rounding to 2 decimal places? Also, what is the type of `totalCredit`? You may need to use `parseFloat()` on it first, if it's a string

Comment: using about math.round when I enter 22212 in input field it return me 22212.00.

Comment: Well, yes... `22212` is a whole number with no decimal places.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  echo number_format(22212 , 2); above code return me 22,212.00 and this is exactly I want in js.

Comment: Well now I'm confused. Your question says you expect `22.212` as the output...? Can you edit the question so it's clear what you're trying to do here

Comment: If you want your number with commas, don't know why you are rounding first, so remove that, do the `.fixed` and then you can use the answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript) to add commas.  Your expected output in the yellow above should be deleted as it is different to what you put in the line above and is confusing

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution:

http://locutus.io/php/strings/number_format/

> Please, stop thinking, jQuery is made for solving any of your JS
>   problems. This problem is not jQuery related, jQuery is mostly (not only) for DOM related stuff

.